# Weak hotkey facility in WMP and IE--why?

Tags: internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, wmp

Why microsoft  didn't even think that in WMP (Windows Media Player) it's hard to pause with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> while in programs like KMPlayer you can just press space and I'm Wondering that why there is FF shortcut (which on my laptop doesn't work) and there is no shortcut for backward seeking (for video playing) and

for IE: there is no shortcut for saving a web page? Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Media Player Plus!](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) plug-in includes an option to play/pause by pressing the space bar (`Settings` - `Hotkeys` - `Local Hotkeys`). You can also configure global (system-wide) hotkeys for forward/backward seeking.

The shortcut in IE for saving a web page is Ctrl+S.

Comment: I mean previous versions of IE.

Comment: Versions earlier than what? Why not use the current version?

Comment: I think it was IE 6. I mean there may be some reason  that why microsoft (that is a big company and should have big group to work on every details) didn't think about puting more hotkeys or for example making Paint or Notepad much better.